# how to recognize raw type

Tags: java, generics, java-8, java-stream, raw-types

I have this exercise:

```
List<Integer> iList = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
Predicate<Integer> p = x -> x%2 == 0; 
List newList = iList.stream()
                    .filter(p)
                    .filter(x -> x>3)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()); 

System.out.println(newList);
```

In my opinion, newList is raw type and not generic, because it was initialized as `List newList` and not as `List<Integer>`.
How is it possible to have a normal result for this exercise and not a compilation error?

If I write:

```
List iList = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
iList.stream()
     .filter(x -> x%2==0)
     .filter(x -> x>3)
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It doesn't compile. Why in the first case does the code compile?

Comment: Raw types are perfectly legal, but very bad practice, as demonstrated by your second code snippet not compiling.

Comment: The second snippet doesnt compile for a simple typo. And the idea that raw types lead to compilation error (by default) is just wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`List newList` is just return type of the stream chain.

Actually you are working with `List<Integer> iList` which is NOT raw type. Therefore there is no compile error

Answer (score 4):

The `Stream` recognizes the sequence of raw objects as a simple `Stream<Object>`. If you want to treat it as `Stream<Integer>`, you have to explicitly declare this fact using `Stream::mapToInt` and boxing the whole `Stream`:

```
List<Integer> newList = iList.stream()                    // Stream
     .mapToInt(obj -> Integer.valueOf(obj.toString()))    // IntStream
     .boxed()                                             // Stream<Integer>
     .filter(x -> x % 2 == 0) 
     .filter(x -> x > 3)
     .collect(Collectors.toList());                       // List<Integer>
```

In the first case, there is obvious for `Stream` to declare self as `Stream<Integer>` since it is created from `List<Integer>`.

---

<sup>Note you have the wrong syntax of the lambda which should be `x -> x % 2 == 0` with an arrow `->`.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You are correct this is a raw type:

```
List newList = iList.stream().filter(p).filter(x>x>3).collect(Collectors.toList()); 
System.out.println(newList);
```

However, raw types are perfectly legal and will not cause a compilation error. They are just very bad practice to use. This is demonstrated by your second code snippet:

```
List iList= Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
iList.stream().filter(x -> x%2 ==0).filter(x -> x>3).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Here since `iList` is a raw type, the compiler doesn't know that `iList` contains `int`'s and treats them as objects, so you cannot use the `%` operator here. The actual error I get is:

```
bad operand types for binary operator '%'
  first type:  Object
  second type: int

bad operand types for binary operator '>'
  first type:  Object
  second type: int
```

---

<sub>Note that this is ignoring your syntax error in your lambdas. The correct syntax is `x -> x > 3` and not `x>x>3`</sub>

Comment: But why does code compile in the first case and doesn't it compile in the second?

Comment: @Adryr83 Because the compiler treats the contents as `Object`'s, so you cannot use `%` or `>` on them

Comment: I used the same methods on both cases. I know that with raw type I have to use only the Object methods. But why in the first case, does the compiler compile? I should have compilation error in both cases.

Comment: @Adryr83 Why? You can have a `List<Object>`. The error is when you try to use the `List<Object>` as a `List<Integer>`

Comment: Yes, but also in the first case I have a List<Object> named newList. In the first case, only iList is generic type, not newList.

Comment: @Adryr83 Only `newList` is a raw type here. The only thing you do with that is print it, which is valid for a `List<Object>`

Comment: Nice explanation @GBlodgett